# Font colour of Note in Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

Is it possible to change the font colour in the Note activity CRM 2016? Mine is white so users do not see what they are typing.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in older versions of CRM where the notes text cannot be seen in newer versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Have you already updated to the latest updated of CRM 2016? I am fairly certain that it has already been fixed by Microsoft, even though I was unable to spot the fix in the release notes. For comparison this was fixed for CRM 2015 in Update 0.3, released in August 2017 ([Unable to view notes fields after updating to Mozilla Firefox version 49.0.1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4018584/update-0-3-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2015)).

If you are unable to upgrade to the latest version, the following unsupported fix can be used. From the [Dynamics Community](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/255153):

> In Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics
> CRM\CRMWeb_static\css\1033\notesv2.css change line #118 to `color: #000000;`
>
> *Replace 1033 with the LCID of the language(s) your users are using.*

The technical explanation of what changed in Chrome and Firefox can be seen here: [CRM 2016 and Firefox 49 issue with notes](http://www.leicht-bewoelkt.de/crm-2016-and-firefox-49-issue-with-notes).